# How can I generate an antiforgery cookie and token in a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to forge a request from within my application but I can't figure out how to get the antiforgery bit of this to work. I need to support some legacy code which can only really be called via a web request.

I've been able to get a token from the controller by faking a HtmlHelper but when it tries to validate it it gives me this exception:

The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that all machines are running the same version of ASP.NET Web Pages and that the  configuration specifies explicit encryption and validation keys.

Code to generate the token:

```
var antiForgeryTokenField = new HtmlHelper(new ViewContext(), new ViewPage()).AntiForgeryToken().ToString();
        var intermediate = antiForgeryTokenField.Substring(antiForgeryTokenField.IndexOf("value=\"") + 8);
        var token = intermediate.Substring(0, intermediate.IndexOf("\""));
```

I'm not sure if its related to the fact that the antiforgery cookie might not be correct?

Comment: Are you using `Javascript` to make these calls?

Comment: You're trying to "forge" an "antiforgery token". Does that sound like something that would be possible? Frankly antiforgery tokens exist to prevent *exactly* what you're trying to do. If you could skirt around it somehow, then they wouldn't be very good at their jobs.

Comment: No, I'm doing this from within the application.
I've heard of people doing this before so it doesn't seem too crazy.

Answer (score 1):

You'd usually place

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

within the `<form>` element, whether created through pure HTML or `@Html.BeginForm(...)`, and then, in the Controller, decorate the method that will receive the POST submission of the form with the attribute `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate an antiforgery cookie and form token using the method [AntiForgery.GetTokens()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.helpers.antiforgery.gettokens?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2). Passing a `null` for `oldCookieToken` will generate a new cookie/token pair.

Attempting to use cookie/token pair extracted from another app will result in the `The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted.` error message which you encountered. As @chris mentioned, it would be a security weakness if this were possible.